# WCF WebHttpServiceHostFactory vs. WebServiceHostFactory

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

What is the difference between WCF's `WebHttpServiceHostFactory` and  `WebServiceHostFactoryhosting`?

Comment: In what namespace did you find the latter class (WebServiceHostFactoryHosting)?

Comment: Are you wondering about the difference between WebServiceHost and WebServiceHostFactory?

Comment: Sorry, there as a typo in my question. Wanted to know the difference between WebHttpServiceHostFactory and WebServiceHostFactory.

Comment: @larsw - No, my question relates to the two different HostFactory's which have the corresponding ServiceHost's - WebHttpServiceHost and WebServiceHost

Comment: In the WCF Web API stack, they included WebHttpServiceHostFactory and I'm just trying to figure out what the difference are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about the HttpServiceHostFactory from the new WCF Web API - http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/44d95f912edf#WCFWebApi%2fHttp%2fSrc%2fMicrosoft.ApplicationServer.Http%2fmicrosoft%2fApplicationServer%2fHttp%2fActivation%2fHttpServiceHostFactory.cs - this factory sets up the service / endpoint using the new HTTP pipeline for WCF (which is on codeplex). The WebServiceHostFactory sets up a service / endpoint using the "traditional" WCF REST style API (i.e., the one which was released with .NET Framework 3.5 and improved in 4.0).

Comment: i see. So WebHttpServiceHost Factory when released will be a replacement of WebServiceHost Factory. Thanks.